# RESUELTO Cliente Servidor python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buscando en la web me encontre con este codigo para la comunicacion entre un cliente y un servidor
**Servidor**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket #utilidades de red y conexion

ip = "192.168.0.18"
puerto = 4445
dataConection = (ip, puerto)
conexionesMaximas = 5

socketServidor = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

socketServidor.bind(dataConection) 
socketServidor.listen(conexionesMaximas) 

print("Esperando conexiones en %s:%s" %(ip, puerto))
cliente, direccion = socketServidor.accept()
print("Conexion establecida con %s:%s" %(direccion[0], direccion[1]))

while True:
    datos = cliente.recv(1024) 
    if datos == "exit":
        msg ="exit"
        cliente.sendall(msg.encode("utf-8"))
        break
    print("RECIBIDO: %s" %datos)
    msg='--Recibido--'
    cliente.sendall(msg.encode("utf-8"))

print("------- CONEXIÓN CERRADA ---------")
socketServidor.close()
```

**cliente**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket #utilidades de red y conexion

ipServidor = "192.168.0.18" #es lo mismo que "localhost" o "0.0.0.0"
puertoServidor = 4445


cliente = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
cliente.connect((ipServidor, puertoServidor))
print("Conectado con el servidor ---> %s:%s" %(ipServidor, puertoServidor))

while True:
    msg = input("> ")
    cliente.sendall(msg.encode("utf-8"))
    respuesta = cliente.recv(4096)
    print(respuesta)
    if respuesta == "exit":
        break

print("------- CONEXIÓN CERRADA ---------")
cliente.close()
```

Al programa le realize unas modificaciones porque originalmente no funcionaba pero lo unico que no logro hacer funcionar es el fragmento de codigo donde se tiene que terminar al introducir "exit", talvez mi problema es muy insignificante pero no conosco mucho sobre python asi que espero me puedan ayudar.
El el codigo si establece comunicacion,envia y recive los mensajes lo que no funciona es el echo de que no termina cuando se introduce exit.

Comment: Debes explicar mejor que entiendes por "no funcionar". Cuál era el comportamiento esperado del código y cuál el que obtienes al ejecutarlo?

Comment: ese while True esta macabro!!, deberia ser algo como `while not respuesta == "exit" :
    msg = input("> ")
    cliente.sendall(msg.encode("utf-8"))
    respuesta = cliente.recv(4096)
    print(respuesta)` ademas agregaria un time.sleep para que tenga su tiempo en enviar la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Problema solucionado, asi quedan los while.

Las modificaciones se realizaron en el if.
**servidor**

```
while True:
    datos = cliente.recv(1024) #El número indica el número maximo de bytes
    if datos == b'exit': #se agrego  una b antes del mensaje
        msg ="exit"
        cliente.sendall(msg.encode("utf-8"))
        break
    print("RECIBIDO: %s" %datos)
    msg='--Recibido--'
```

**cliente**

```
while True:
    msg = input("> ")
    cliente.sendall(msg.encode("utf-8"))
    respuesta = cliente.recv(4096)
    print(respuesta)
    if respuesta == b'exit': #se agrego  una b antes del mensaje
        break
cliente.sendall(msg.encode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo, tanto cliente como servidor deben terminar cuando escribes `"exit"` en el cliente. Pero funciona así: Cuando el servidor reciba `"exit"`, lo devuelve al cliente, y el servidor termina. A su vez, el cliente al recibir `"exit"`, termina.

El problema que veo es que el servidor solo termina y envia `"exit"` al cliente cuando reciba `"b's'"`, no `"exit"`. Puede ser que esto hacía parte del código original.

```
# Esta es la condición para que el servidor termine y envíe
# "exit" al cliente
if datos == "b's'": 
        msg ="exit"
        cliente.sendall(msg.encode("utf-8"))
        break
```

Comment: una discullpa en lugar de "b's'" es exit pero no funciona

Comment: El problema no es que faltara una `b`, es que los datos enviados y recibidos son bytes, no strings. Por eso cuando usas el metodo `sendall()` al mensaje, que es string, lo codificas con el método `encode()`. Y cuando evaluabas en el if, siempre era falso ya que `"exit"` no es igual a `b"exit"`. La `b` es para diferenciar los bytes de los strings.